# sed/grep - get text between two strings (html)

Tags: regex, macos, bash, unix, sed

I am trying to extract "pagename" from the following:

```
<a class="timetable work" href="http://www.test.com/pagename?tag=meta376">Test</a>
```

I tried to get it to work using "sed" but it only says invalid command code.

What line of code would you guys suggest to get the pagename? By the way: This is not a single line but there is more content on the same line - but that should not make a difference as it should just matter what is between the limiters, right?

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Are you trying to just extract the word "pagename" from that line?  Please show an example of output that you want.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to extract?

Comment: Well, I try to get "pagename", yes. But the document is quite big with many links. So the limiters should be between `<a class="timetable work" href="http://www.test.com/` and `?tag=meta376">Test</a>`

Comment: The right way to do this is to parse the HTML. Use a HTML parser in Perl, Python, Ruby or some other scripting language. Get the element by its tag/class name(s). Get the href attribute. Parse the URL and extract the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F"[/?]" '/timetable work/ {print $4}'file
pagename
```

It search for a line containing `timetable work`, then print fourth field using `\` or `?` as separator.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented, if you want to extract `"<a class="timetable work" href="test.com/"; and "?tag=meta376">Test</a>"` you can use the following regex:

```
<a class="timetable.*?<\/a>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qI5yH9/1)**

If you want to grab the content just surround the regex with capturing groups:

```
(<a class="timetable.*?<\/a>)
```

The match is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [9-80]  `<a class="timetable work" href="test.com/"; and "?tag=meta376">Test</a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
sed 's_^.*<a [^<>]* href="https*://[^/]*/\([^"?]*\).*$_\1_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving you exactly what you asked for using exactly the delimiters you told us to use:

```
$ sed -n 's|.*<a class="timetable work" href="http://www\.test\.com/\(.*\)?tag=meta376">Test</a>|\1|p' file
pagename
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be tempting to handle this using a regular expression but here's an alternative.

You are trying to parse some HTML, so use an HTML parser. Here's an example in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use URI::URL;

my $filename = 'file.html'; 
my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new($filename);

while (my $anchor = $parser->get_tag('a')) {
    next unless defined(my $class = $anchor->get_attr('class'));
    next unless $class =~ /\btimetable\b/ and $class =~ /\bwork\b/;    
    my $url = url $anchor->get_attr('href');    
    say substr($url->path, 1);
}
```

Parse the HTML using [`HTML::TokeParser::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm). loop through the `<a>` tags, skipping any that don't have the correct classes defined. For the ones that do, use [`URI::URL`](http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/URI/URL.pm) to parse the url and extract the "path" component (which in your case, would be "/pagename"). As you didn't want the leading slash, I used `substr` to remove the first character.

Output:

```
pagename
```

I know it's much longer than a single regex but it's also a **lot** more robust and will continue to work even when the format of your HTML changes slightly in the future. HTML parsers exist for a reason :)